# Electron JS install error - Error: EACCES: permission denied

Tags: node.js, electron

getting error while installing ElectronJS,

Error:

```
Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/lib/node_modules/electron/.electron'
```

command tried,

```
sudo npm install -g electron
sudo npm install -g electron-prebuilt
```

how to resolve this permission issue?

Answer (score 22):

You can try with the following command

```
sudo npm install -g electron --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
```

i hope it will be work

Answer (score 11):

Solved my issue by appending **--unsafe-perm=true**

command:

```
sudo npm install -g electron --unsafe-perm=true
```

> unsafe-perm

**Default:** false if running as root, true otherwise

**Type: Boolean**
Set to true to suppress the UID/GID switching when running package scripts. If set explicitly to false, then installing as a non-root user will fail.

Answer (score 2):

change npm global module default folder , follow this guide

https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

I had a similar problem with npm on my mac and windows system and i fixed them by changing the npm default directory to another directory by following option 2 in the tutorial

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar problem. I fixed it by changing folder permissions.

Check the current folder permissions of the /usr/lib/node_modules directory by running the following command:

`ls -l /usr/lib | grep "node_modules`

Your output will probably be:

`drwxr-xr-x  3 root root {timestamp} node_modules`

Change the owner of the directory to the current user by running the following command:

`sudo chown -R current_username:current_username /usr/bin/node_modules`

**Note - Do not run `sudo` with any npm command! More information [here](https://medium.com/@ExplosionPills/dont-use-sudo-with-npm-still-66e609f5f92).**

Hope this Helps :)

Answer (score 0):

With the same message, it could also be that an eletron app is already running using that executable... So the electron binary is actually in use.

In that case, just kill the electron app currently running.